# How to handle multiple type of clustering in Google Map iOS SDK

Tags: ios, google-maps

I am able to show 2 different kind of clusters by creating 2 GClusterManager objects. But issue is cluster items are reset to newly created GClusterManager object, so when we zoom in map, items of first GClusterManager object are nor breaking into individual markers. I am using below classes for clustering:

https://github.com/DDRBoxman/google-maps-ios-utils

Comment: If you can share a screenshot displaying the issue along with the code to create cluster on Google maps that will be helpful. So you mean to say only one cluster is not breaking into individual markers and the second one is? This seems to be a bug in the library, you can go ahead and report a bug to the concerned developer so that he can fix this issue.

Comment: I want to display 2 types of cluster, for eg. one group of cluster in red color icon and other group of cluster in blue colored icon where both type of clusters represents 2 different type of data.

Comment: @PoojaSharma me too need this exact scenario can you pls explain how you create two types of manager and you handled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every marker has a marker.userData value.

now Go into GDefaultClusterRenderer.m and look at this function and play around here:

```
- (void)clustersChanged:(NSSet*)clusters {
    for (GMSMarker *marker in _markerCache) {
        marker.map = nil;
    }

    [_markerCache removeAllObjects];

    for (id <GCluster> cluster in clusters) {
        GMSMarker *marker;
        marker = [[GMSMarker alloc] init];
        [_markerCache addObject:marker];

        marker.userData = cluster.marker.userData;

        NSUInteger count = cluster.items.count;
        if (count > 1) {
            marker.icon = [self generateClusterIconWithCount:count];
            NSMutableDictionary *newUserData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:marker.userData];
            [newUserData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:@"isCluster"];
            marker.userData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:newUserData];
        }
        else {
            marker.icon = cluster.marker.icon;
            marker.groundAnchor = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5);
            NSMutableDictionary *newUserData = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:marker.userData];
            [newUserData setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] forKey:@"isCluster"];
            marker.userData = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:newUserData];
        }

        marker.position = cluster.marker.position;
        marker.map = _map;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unobvious but when you add cluster items to GMUClusterManager item is adding to GMUClusterAlgorithm in fact. You need to be sure that you are creating cluster manager appropriately. So when you clear items from one of them `[clusterManager clearItems]`  other manager clusters stay relevant.

```
// Common clusters setup

id<GMUClusterIconGenerator> iconGenerator = [[GMUDefaultClusterIconGenerator alloc] init];

PinItemClusterRenderer *pin_renderer = [[PinItemClusterRenderer alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView
                                                               clusterIconGenerator:iconGenerator];

//Pin clusters setup

id<GMUClusterAlgorithm> pin_algorithm =
[[GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm alloc] init];

[pin_renderer setMapView:self.mapView];
pin_cluster_manager =
[[GMUClusterManager alloc] initWithMap:self.mapView
                             algorithm:pin_algorithm
                              renderer:pin_renderer];


//Record clusterSetup

id<GMUClusterAlgorithm> record_algorithm =
[[GMUNonHierarchicalDistanceBasedAlgorithm alloc] init];
RecordItemClusterRenderer *record_renderer = [[RecordItemClusterRenderer alloc] initWithMapView:self.mapView
                                                                           clusterIconGenerator:iconGenerator];
[record_renderer setMapView:self.mapView];
record_cluster_manager =  [[GMUClusterManager alloc] initWithMap:self.mapView
                                                       algorithm:record_algorithm
                                                        renderer:record_renderer];
```

this two cluster generators work work well for me. Though now I have a problem with those clusters overlap each other.

[image]